# Using xDB Data Migration Tool 2.0.2

Tags: xdb, upgrade, mongodb, migration

Is there a need for `down time` while tool is running?

If not, should we `disable` analytics during the process?

Thinking the site should be live but I do not want to have new data going into `Mongo` that will not be captured by the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data migration is an asynchronous process and you don't need any down time, also It is recommended to install xDB Data Migration Tool in Content Management server. So I guess  during the migration you can use your Sitecore server like how you use regularly, I mean analytics can be enabled while running data migration.

From [Sitecore Document](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/F5AB4212C143456D8E6104095AE1278B.ashx)

> Depending on the amount of data you have in MongoDB, it may take hours
>   - or even days - to migrate all of your data. The migration process runs asynchronously on the Sitecore server, so you can continue to use
>   your Sitecore server during the migration process.